# Laravel collection group by with sum

Tags: php, laravel, collections, grouping

I'm trying to group collection by value but also sum nested collection. I'm getting data from google analytics.

[image: Collection screenshot]

For example when you look at Safari (in-app) I just need to sum all values of key 'sessions' in nested collections. How can I do this?
I have only idea to loop all collections and sum values but that doesnt seems to be good idea.

I want to show table with 2 columns: browser and sessions

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
$result = $collection->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return [$key => $item->sum('sessions')];
});
```